# Is it possible to switch limit from inside to outside of integral in this case?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, analysis, derivatives

Let $C$ be an open connected subset of $\mathbb{C}$.

Let $f:[a,b]\times C \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a function.

Assume $f(-,z):[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is continuous and $f(t,-):C\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is differentiable.

Also assume that $\frac{\partial f(-,z)}{\partial z}:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is continuous.

Define $F(z)=\int_a^b f(t,z) dt, \forall z\in C$.

Then,

(1) is $F$ differentiable?

(2) is $F'(z)=\int_a^b \frac{\partial f(t,z)}{\partial z} dt$?

Comment: Is your differentiability $\mathbb{R}$-differentiability or $\mathbb{C}$-differentiability?

Comment: @Siminore I meant complex differentiability. I think this wouldn't change the result.

Comment: And therefore $f(t,\cdot)$ is an analytic function?

Comment: If that is necessary, yes it is.

Comment: Uhm... is your conjecture true if $f(t,z)=\sum_{n} a_n(t) (z-z_0)^n$?

Comment: This will be true if you have some estimate on the function $f$. Explicitely, (1) and (2) hold true as soon as for any compact set $K\subset C$, you have an estimate of the form $\vert f(t,z)\vert\leq g(t)$ for $(t,z)\in [a,b]\times K$, where $g(t)$ does not depend on $z\in K$ and $g$ is integrable on $[a,b]$. For example, this holds if $f(t,z)$ is continuous in both variables (jointly); in this case you can take a constant "dominating function" $g$.